# How do I reverse an index number into the character it represents in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, indexing, reverse

I have a code in which I am attempting to reverse a certain string. I have received instructions to only use index to do this, so I used index, and came to a halt when I found this. Here is my code first, for context.

```
emptyList = []
Len = len(var)
for i in range(Len, 0, -1):
    emptyList.append(i)

print(emptyList)
```

My problem is that whenever I print the variable `emptyList`, I only get a list of numbers, like such:
`[3, 2, 1]`

I want the numbers to represent their character, like **3 = G**, **2 = O**. How do I do that?

Comment: You don't use `index` to reverse a string.  That's silly advice.

Answer (score 0):

Use `emptyList.append(var[i-1])` not just `i`.

Comment: That's fair advice, but it's going to fail, because for a 5-letter string, `i` will run 5,4,3,2,1; var[5] is out of bounds.  Easy fix.

Comment: Yep my bad let me edit

Comment: Good try, but that will miss the last letter because it doesn't generate 0.  Let me fix it.

Comment: Is it fine now? I didn’t want to paste the whole code so just pasted the parts to be changed

Comment: Well, I fixed it, and then you added the `range` line which broke it again.  I think using `i-1` is more sensible than having a weird range.

Comment: Oh sorry I hadn’t noticed your fix let me revert. Yep gtg now thanks. Silly mistakes